# Facebook connect: Do I need an app id for every domain?

Tags: api, facebook, comments

Hey Guys, I'm setting up a commenting system for a group of sites that I have.

With facebook connect, Is there a way for me to avoid getting an app id for every domain I want to use? do commenting systems like socialble.es force you to get an app id?

Sites like Echo and Disqus seem to iframe or jsonp in tools from their own domain, so I assume they only need an app_id for their own domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer seems to be that you do.